# Como mostrar un texto con formato en un richedit

Tags: delphi, pascal, freepascal, lazarus

Al guardar un texto enriquecido en la BD sql server lo hace OK, se guarda lo siguiente:

{\rtf1\fbidis\ansi\ansicpg0\uc1\deff0\deflang0\deflangfe0{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil Arial;}}{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue255;\red0\green0\blue128;\red128\green0\blue0;\red0\green128\blue0;\red255\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;}      \pard\fi0\li0\ql\ri0\cbpat6\sb0\sa0\itap0 \plain \f0\b\fs20\chcbpat6\cf5 sefgssdfsdf\par}

al intentar cargar esto en un richedit sale en texto plano sin formato, deberia mostrar un texto de color rojo.

Estoy intentando con esto pero no logro que salga el texto con el formato

```
ReadStream := TStringStream.Create(TextoEnriquecido);
FormatStream := TStringStream.Create(
Format(ReadStream.DataString, [TextoEnriquecido]));
richedit.Lines.LoadFromStream(FormatStream);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vas bien encaminado, aunque es más simple de lo que parece.

Siguiendo el ejemplo con el código que utilizas, basta con utilizar el siguiente código:

```
var
  ReadStream:TStringStream;
  sTexto:string;
begin
  // Cargar el texto de Base de Datos
  ADOQuery1.Open;
  sTexto := ADOQuery1.FieldByName('Texto').AsString;
  // PlainText a false para cargar el texto (obligatorio)
  RichEdit1.PlainText := False;
  // Crear el stream con el texto de BD
  ReadStream := TStringStream.Create(sTexto);
  try
    // Cargarlo en el richedit
    RichEdit1.Lines.LoadFromStream(ReadStream);
  finally
    FreeAndNil(ReadStream);
  end;
```

Lo realmente importante es utilizar correctamente la propiedad `PlainText`.

Lo he dividido en 2 partes para que quede más claro. Primero carga es texto en una variable y luego lo vuelca sobre el control, aunque no sería necesaria la variable `sTexto` para hacerlo en un sólo paso.

Otra opción (que no comentas) es utilizar un componente TDBRichEdit, que carga el texto correctamente, sin necesidad de código.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola German gracias por responder, estoy usando delphi xe4 y no tengo la propiedad PlainText  en el richedit que puedo hacer?

Comment: Que pasa que este componente que usamos fue modificado y esa propiedad no la tengo segun me dicen aca ya el componente lo debe cargar con el formato, pero que tengo que quitarle los caracteres raros con rtf o algo aso, no he podido resolver, tu codigo me funciona perfecto con un RichEdit clasico, pero el mio esta modificado, gracias de todas formas